# How to interact with the button using Selenium webdriver and Python

Tags: python, selenium, xpath, css-selectors, webdriverwait

I want to try filling out the form on this page: https://konzinfoidopont.mfa.gov.hu.
However, when I try to select the dropdown menu and click it, I get the following error:

```
selenium.common.exceptions.ElementNotInteractableException: Message: .
```

This is the mentioned button:

```
<button class="btn btn-sm btn-primary dropdown-toggle w-100" data-toggle="modal" data-target="#modal2">Helyszín kiválasztása</button>
```

And my code yet:

```
from selenium import webdriver
from selenium.webdriver.common.by import By
import time

url = "https://konzinfoidopont.mfa.gov.hu"

driver = webdriver.Safari()
driver.get(url)
time.sleep(5)
elem = driver.find_element(By.CSS_SELECTOR, "#label1 > button")
elem.click()
```

Comment: Sounds like you're trying to click on a disabled button. This isn't enough information/context to really diagnose the issue though, e.g. there could be CSS styles that affect the button or other elements that are obscuring the button.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The desired element is within a [Modal Dialog Box](https://www.w3schools.com/Bootstrap/bootstrap_modal.asp), so to click on the ***clickable*** element you need to induce [WebDriverWait](https://stackoverflow.com/a/59130336/7429447) for the [*element_to_be_clickable()*](https://stackoverflow.com/a/54194511/7429447) and you can use either of the following [*locator strategies*](https://stackoverflow.com/a/48056120/7429447):

- Using *CSS_SELECTOR*:

  ```
  driver.execute("get", {'url': 'https://konzinfoidopont.mfa.gov.hu/'})
  driver.execute_script("arguments[0].click();", WebDriverWait(driver, 20).until(EC.element_to_be_clickable((By.CSS_SELECTOR, "button.btn.btn-sm.btn-primary.dropdown-toggle[data-toggle='modal']"))))
  ```
- Using *XPATH*:

  ```
  driver.execute("get", {'url': 'https://konzinfoidopont.mfa.gov.hu/'})     
  driver.execute_script("arguments[0].click();", WebDriverWait(driver, 20).until(EC.element_to_be_clickable((By.XPATH, "//button[contains(@class, 'btn btn-sm btn-primary dropdown-toggle') and @data-toggle='modal'][contains(@data-target, 'modal2') and text()='Helyszín kiválasztása']"))))
  ```
- **Note**: You have to add the following imports :

  ```
  from selenium.webdriver.support.ui import WebDriverWait
  from selenium.webdriver.common.by import By
  from selenium.webdriver.support import expected_conditions as EC
  ```
- Browser snapshot:

[image: konzinfoidopont]

Comment: Thank you! I tried your method and I still get the error message that the element is not interactable.

Comment: I wondered if another method would be possible by clicking the choices as radio inputs. However, trying this I get a no such element exception.

Comment: @vate This isn't a radio button/input but a `<button>` element. Checkout the updated answer and let me know the status.

Comment: Glad to be able to help you out.